# continuously Blinking QPushButton not worked right in Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I want to blinking a QPushButton while my program runing , i try to make it with thread , it was  working for a few time then it was not binking anymore

```
`    def blinker_station(self,station):
     while(1):
       #print('station,self.stationblinkervalue[station] : ',station,self.stationblinkervalue[station]) 
       if self.stationblinkervalue[station]==2 :
         self.buttom_stations[station].setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
         
         time.sleep(0.5)
        
         time.sleep(0.5)
       elif self.stationblinkervalue[station]==1:
         self.buttom_stations[station].setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
     
     time.sleep(1)
     
     self.buttom_stations[station].setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
     
     time.sleep(0.5)
    
     time.sleep(0.5)
   elif self.stationblinkervalue[station]==0:
     self.buttom_stations[station].setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
     
     time.sleep(0.5)
     
     time.sleep(0.5)`
```

that is , what i wrote at the end of my MainWindows init :

```
for i in range(len(self.stationMatrix)):
          random.seed(5)
         
          self.station_threading_blinker.append(threading.Thread(target=self.blinker_station, args=(i,)))
          self.station_threading_blinker[-1].start()
          time.sleep(random.random()+1)
```

can someone help me in this problem , how can i let my QPushButton continuously Blinking

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if switching stylesheet to change the background colour is the most efficient way to make a button blink, but a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html) is the way to go to do the timing.

You set a short interval on a timer (like 500 msec) and connect its timeout signal to a method to switch the background colour on the button.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.blinker = QPushButton("I'm blinking")
        layout.addWidget(self.blinker)

        self.background_colour = 'red'

        self.blink_timer = QTimer()
        self.blink_timer.setInterval(500)
        self.blink_timer.timeout.connect(self.switch_background_colour)
        self.blink_timer.start()

    def switch_background_colour(self):
        if self.background_colour == 'red':
            self.background_colour = 'white'
        elif self.background_colour == 'white':
            self.background_colour = 'red'

        self.blinker.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.background_colour}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: thx ,but  I got this output : Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Comment: Where is the thread coming from? There is no thread in your own code, and not in my code. As far as I can see, there is no need to use a thread.

Comment: i calll the function (def blinker_station(self,station):) in my code with thread

Comment: Please edit your code to show how you're using the thread. Now it's not clear why you're using it.

Comment: in the end of my MainWindiws __init__ I wrote :
        for i in range(len(self.stationMatrix)):
                  random.seed(5)
                 
                  self.station_threading_blinker.append(threading.Thread(target=self.blinker_station, args=(i,)))
                  self.station_threading_blinker[-1].start()
                  time.sleep(random.random()+1)

Comment: That's not helping much. There are still many references to unknown elements. Either provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or I can't help you any further. I've shown you how to make a button blink. Without knowledge of the structure of your code it's impossible to show you how to implement it.

Comment: @Hasan: 1. We cannot give valid answers if you don't provide sufficient code and context; 2. Comments don't support code formatting, if you want to update your question, then click the edit link.

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution Now !

that what i write i th MainWindows Init :

```
        for self.i in range(len(self.stationMatrix)):
                  self.worker_thread.append(WorkerThread())
                  self.worker_thread[self.i].gui_text = self.i
                  self.worker_thread[self.i].blinker_mode = 0
                  self.worker_thread[self.i].job_done.connect(self.on_job_done)
                  self.worker_thread[self.i].start()
                  time.sleep(0.5)
     #End of INIT             
#########################################################################################################
    def on_job_done(self, t):
        #print("Generated string : ", t)
        # self.buttom_stations[t[1]].setStyleSheet(t[0])
        matrix=t.split('/')
        self.buttom_stations[int(matrix[1])].setStyleSheet(matrix[0])
```

that is the other class WorkerThread which make the work :

```
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    job_done = QtCore.pyqtSignal('QString')
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui_text = None
        self.blinker_mode = None
        self.x="background-color: white"
    def do_work(self):
        
        t=' '
        while(1):
         #   print(self.gui_text)
            if self.blinker_mode==1:
             if self.x =="background-color: red" : 
                 t="background-color: white"+'/'+str(self.gui_text)
                 self.job_done.emit(t)
                 self.x="background-color: white"
                 time.sleep(0.5)
             if self.x =="background-color: white" :
              t="background-color: red"+'/'+str(self.gui_text)
              self.job_done.emit(t)
              self.x="background-color: red"
              time.sleep(0.5)
            if self.blinker_mode==0:
            #   if self.x =="background-color: white" : 
                 t="background-color: white"+'/'+str(self.gui_text)
                 self.job_done.emit(t)
                 self.x="background-color: white"
                 time.sleep(1)
            if self.blinker_mode==2:
            #   if self.x =="background-color: red" : 
                 t="background-color: red"+'/'+str(self.gui_text)
                 self.job_done.emit(t)
                 self.x="background-color: red"
                 time.sleep(1)
             
            
    def run(self):
        self.do_work()
```

and now if i want to change the blinking i just need to call :

self.worker_thread[index_of_worker].blinker_mode = Mode_of_blinker